# Install xgboost h2o r

Tags: r, macos

I am trying to install XGBoost-enabled H2O in r. I found the link https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/ensembles-stacking/stacked_ensemble_h2o_xgboost.Rmd

it suggested to use brew install gcc --without-multilib. I tried this but error message. Then I attempted brew install gcc it apparently give no error message.

However, When I Check, I get the message that "Cannot build a XGboost model - no backend found."

Comment: The tutorial link is from 2017. Presently, at least for Linux OS you don't need a special version of H2O to run XGBoost. See the link for [supported platforms](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have installed latest version of H2O. But how can I enable XGboost in it? on window in Rstudio

Comment: H2O doesn't have XGboost on Windows. [See](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#limitations)

Comment: Thanks I know this. But what is solution how to use XGboost with H2O in R or python even.

Comment: Find a mac or Linux OS that satisfies criteria in the link give before, and then install H2O. It'll come with XGBoost.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me.